# I am getting first character of each name instead of full name

Tags: php, html

I am fetching a complete column from a table and make a dropdown of all the fetched columns. But I am getting only the first character of each name in a dropdown.

```
 $sql= "SELECT Name from mytable";
 $app=$conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
 echo "<select name='sub1'>";
 foreach($app as $n){
  echo "<option value='".$n['Name']."'>".$n['Name']."</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

"mytable"=table name.
"Name"=column name.
I expected complete name should be shown in dropdown

Comment: Add `var_dump($app);` to the bottom to check the contents of the $app array.

Comment: I checked it by print_r , I am getting all the content. but I think Problem may be in foreach loop

Comment: Edit your question to give us some sample lines from $app array.

Comment: print_r ($app);       getting on browser=   Array ( [0] => raj [1] => pooja [2] => jarin [3] => Hansraj [4] => sanjay [5] => murad )

Comment: is an option here to attach a print screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC instead of PDO::FETCH_COLUMN in fetchAll method.

Remove:

```
 $app=$conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Add:

```
 $app=$conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```